# Async function in mocha before() is alway finished before it() spec?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, mocha.js

I have a callback function in `before()` which is for cleaning database. 
Is everything in `before()` guaranteed to finish before `it()` starts?

```
before(function(){
   db.collection('user').remove({}, function(res){}); // is it guaranteed to finish before it()? 
});

it('test spec', function(done){
  // do the test
});

after(function(){
});
```

Comment: This should work.  You just need to make sure you return a promise from your `before` handler.  E.g. `before(function () { return db.collection...}`

Answer (score 141, accepted):

**For new mocha versions :**

You can now return a promise to mocha, and mocha will wait for it to complete before proceeding. For example, the following test will pass :

```
let a = 0;
before(() => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      a = 1;
      resolve();
    }, 200);
  });
});
it('a should be set to 1', () => {
  assert(a === 1);
});
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises)

**For older mocha versions :**

If you want your asynchronous request to be completed before everything else happens, you need to use the `done` parameter in your before request, and call it in the callback.

Mocha will then wait until `done` is called to start processing the following blocks.

```
before(function (done) {
   db.collection('user').remove({}, function (res) { done(); }); // It is now guaranteed to finish before 'it' starts.
})

it('test spec', function (done) {
  // execute test
});

after(function() {});
```

You should be careful though, as not stubbing the database for unit testing may strongly slow the execution, as requests in a database may be pretty long compared to simple code execution.

For more information, see the [Mocha documentation](https://mochajs.org/#asynchronous-code).

Comment: Note that if the asynchronous operation takes too long, you will get a failure message that isn't very helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48087201/1827734

Comment: Mocha now supports promises in hooks - https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises .  No need to use `done`. Just return a promise.

Comment: You can also : `before(function () {
   return db.collection('user').remove({});
})` since `remove()` returns a promise, no need to wrap it in a `new Promise()`

Answer (score 11):

Hopefully your db.collection() should return a promise. If yes then you can also use async keyword in before()

```
// Note: I am using Mocha 5.2.0.
before(async function(){
   await db.collection('user').remove({}, function(res){}); // it is now guaranteed to finish before it()
});
```

Comment: How about for `after()`? My `await` works fine when I call it in `before()` (it deletes a DB entry), but if I put the exact same thing into `after()`, it does not delete anything by the time a second `describe()...it()` begins and fails due to the data not being removed.

Answer (score -1):

you can use an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression).

Here is an example:

```js
before(function () {
    (async () => {
        try {
            await mongoose.connect(mongo.url, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    })();
});
```