# Mocha test fails with error from "before all" hook

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

From what I understand, the mocha test framework will throw this error if some error occurs in the `before` method:

```
> $(npm bin)/mocha test/*.js


  1) "before all" hook
```

I've tried many different things to try and catch this error, but nothing seems to be working:

```
before(function(done) {
  server = require('../app')
  try {
    server.listen(process.env.PORT)
    done()
    // server.initialize()
    //   .then(() => {
    //     console.info('listening on', process.env.PORT)
    //     server.listen(process.env.PORT, done)
    //   })
    //   .catch(err => {
    //     console.log(err)
    //     done(err)
    //   })
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('outer error', err)
    done(err)
  }
})
```

From the commented out code, you can see that the server has an asynchronous operation I need to complete before the server actually starts listening. The only thing that seems to be working is to initialize the server outside of the `before` block and either call `done()` immediately in the `before` function, or pass a function that doesn't take a parameter. However this is still a problem since the server isn't initialized by the time the test starts.

Maddeningly, this code works when I connect to a debugger, so I can't even inspect to see what's wrong.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As I was posting this question, I stumbled on [this bug](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/issues/1292) which led me to the discovery that I need to make a call to `this.enableTimeouts(false)` in the beginning of the `before` function, like so:

```
let server
before(function(done) {
  this.enableTimeouts(false)  <----
  server = require('../app')
  server.initialize()
    .then(() => {
      console.info('listening on', process.env.PORT)
      server.listen(process.env.PORT, done)
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err)
      done(err)
    })
})
```

Hopefully this helps someone else a few hours of debugging.

Answer (score 1):

It has been a little time since it was asked but for the future readers here we go:

You can run your test with `mocha test/*.js --timeout 5000` command. That's it.

But if you run your test with `npm test` command, just edit your `package.json` file 
like that:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon ./bin/www",
    "test": "mocha --exit --recursive --timeout 5000" // add this line
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't know whether anyone still watches this thread but I still have the error with a time-out, funny thing is trying to run the test twice works. Using mocha chai test on the express app trying to get sequelize to destroy. This is the part I think causes the error:

> "1) /reader before all" hook in "/readers"

> Validation error

```js
describe("/readers", () => {
    before(async () => Reader.sequelize.sync());
    beforeEach(async () => {
        await Reader.destroy({ where: {} });
    });
});
```