# How do I solve the before all error when running mocha tests?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

This error started to appear in my mocha test suite recently and the answers I've found so far don't really help understand what the issue is.

The error I get is:

```
/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/test_suite/test/integration/adds_image_and_confirms_style_via_edit_button.js
Thu Jul 25 2019 15:46:22 GMT+0000 (utc)
DB Reset complete!
Orgs in database
[ 102 ]
(node:25283) DeprecationWarning: collection.update is deprecated. Use updateOne, updateMany, or bulkWrite instead.
(node:25283) DeprecationWarning: collection.remove is deprecated. Use deleteOne, deleteMany, or bulkWrite instead.
Entering pin: null
    1) "before all" hook: ret

  0 passing (8s)
  1 failing

  1) Admin adds survey with rich text and confirms style via edit button
 "before all" hook: ret:
     TypeError: each key must be a number of string; got object
      at keys.forEach.key (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1971:21)
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
      at Promise.all.then.keys (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1966:16)
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
  From: Task: WebElement.sendKeys()
      at Driver.schedule (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:414:17)
      at WebElementPromise.schedule_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1820:25)
      at WebElementPromise.sendKeys (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:1983:19)
      at test/init.js:115:14
      at node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:753:14
      at TaskQueue.execute_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2736:14)
      at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2719:21)
      at asyncRun (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2642:25)
      at node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
  From: Task: <anonymous>
      at pollCondition (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2178:16)
      at node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2174:9
      at new ManagedPromise (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1029:7)
      at node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2173:14
      at TaskQueue.execute_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2736:14)
      at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2719:21)
      at asyncRun (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2595:27)
      at node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
  From: Task: <anonymous wait>
      at ControlFlow.wait (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2171:17)
      at Driver.wait (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/webdriver.js:749:29)
      at Object.kTest.customSendKeys (test/init.js:112:25)
      at Object.kTest.enterPin (test/init.js:137:11)
      at test/integration/adds_image_and_confirms_style_via_edit_button.js:93:19
      at ManagedPromise.invokeCallback_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:1315:14)
      at TaskQueue.execute_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2736:14)
      at TaskQueue.executeNext_ (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2719:21)
      at asyncRun (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2595:27)
      at node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:639:7
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:228:7)
  From: Task: Admin adds survey with rich text and confirms style via edit button
   "before all" hook: ret
      at Context.ret (node_modules/selenium-webdriver/testing/index.js:137:10)
```

Looking at https://romaklimenko.github.io/curves/docs/mocha.html, I am not sure what `ret` is, so I can't see if that is where the issue is. The test looks something like this, but this happens on other tests, and these tests were fine before, so unsure how to debug. Any advice would be helpful. I should also mention this happens on my Jenkins server, and only occasionally when I run the tests locally.

```
Test.describe("Adds image and confirms style via edit button\n", function() {
    this.timeout(mochaTimeOut);

Test.before(function(done) {
    kTest.logFilename(__filename);
    kTest.setup().then(function() {
        return Factory.createA({
            ...
        });
    }).then(function () {
        return Factory.createB({
            ...
        });
    }).then(function () {
        return Factory.createC({
            ...
        });
    }).then(function () {
        return Factory.createD({
            ...
        });
    }).then(function () {
        kTest.login(testVariables.email, testVariables.password);
    }).then(function () {
        var elementSelector = 'h3';
        var element = kTest.driver.findElement(By.css(elementSelector));
        element.getText().then(function(text) {
            assert.equal(text, "Enter your pin");
        });
    }).then(function() {
        return adminDb.Users.findOne({userId: testVariables.userId});
    }).then(function(admin) {
        kTest.enterPin(admin.textPin, testVariables.password);
    }).then(function() {
        var button = kTest.driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className('fa-bars')), K_TEST_TIMEOUT);
        button.click();

        kTest.driver.findElement(By.className("side_menu_q")).click();

        kTest.driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.id("selectOption")), K_TEST_TIMEOUT);
        var elementSelector = "h4";
        var element = kTest.driver.findElement(By.css(elementSelector));
        element.getText().then(function(val) {
            assert.equal(val, "IMAGE NAMES");
        });
    }).then(function() {
        done();
    }).catch(function(err) {
        throw err;
    });
});
...
});
```

`enableTimeouts` did not work, btw

[Mocha test fails with error from "before all" hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087176/mocha-test-fails-with-error-from-before-all-hook)