# Npm install inside before() not waiting for code to complete

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, mocha.js, es6-promise

I want to run my program and afterwards run tests to see if everything was done properly. I am running `npm start` command inside `before` function, but it does not work.

I have checked and tried [Async function in mocha before() is alway finished before it() spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723374/async-function-in-mocha-before-is-alway-finished-before-it-spec/24862303) as such:

```js
return new Promise((resolve) => {
   execa('npm start')
   process.chdir('../Project')
   console.log(process.cwd());
   resolve()
});
```

and

```js
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  execa('npm start')
    .then(function() {
      process.chdir('../Project')
      console.log(process.cwd());
      resolve()
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Error')
      return reject(new Error(err))
    })
});
```

However `console.log` is executing before `npm start` finishes.

I have also checked 
[In mocha testing while calling asynchronous function how to avoid the timeout Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16607039/in-mocha-testing-while-calling-asynchronous-function-how-to-avoid-the-timeout-er)
and at the moment in my `package.json` file test start like this: `"test": "mocha --timeout 30000"`. This does not help.

My code:

`npm start` executes following code:

```js
try {
  process.chdir('../')
  var packages = ['webpack']
  var args = ['install', '--save', '--save-exact']

  let exec = args.concat(packages, ['--verbose'])

  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    execa('npm', exec)
    .then(function() {
      console.log(`Current directory: ${process.cwd()}`);
      console.log(`Execa instaled: `, exec);
      return execa('npm', ['install'])
    })
    .then(function() {
      console.log('Success. Installed packages in', dir);
      resolve()
    })
    .catch(function() {
      console.log('Error')
      return reject(new Error('npm installation failed'))
    })
  })
} catch (err) {
  console.error(`chdir: ${err}`);
}
```

Out of all things I tried mocha is either does not wait for the script to finish or the script finishes and then mocha is throwing `Error: Timeout of 30000ms exceeded.`

How do I do it properly? I expect that this is my misunderstanding of the Promises.

Comment: If you can let do it to Jenkins(ci) with a simple pipeline: 1) npm install  2) run linting 3) run all tests 4) save the artifact

Comment: @Vash72 Not really. I am trying to create a program that is tested beforehand, during a development stage. Probably even using a BDD approach