# node.js mocha before function runs after test execution

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

I have moved this around so much and tried with `done()`, `async`and chaining `then()`, moving the `describe()` around and my latest attempt was to return a promise in the before as [Async function in mocha before() is alway finished before it() spec?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723374/async-function-in-mocha-before-is-alway-finished-before-it-spec) suggested.

The `console.log('finished!')` that indicates the tables have been created is printed way after `console.log('starting tests')` that indicates the start of the tests.

I should mention that somehow the user table is created and all the user tests works like a charm.

All of my tests fail because they try to perform operations on tables that does not exist. I am not sure of much anymore. How can I make sure the `before`runs before the actual tests?

```js
describe('', async () => {
    before('setting up database', async () => {
        return new Promise(async resolve => {
            await db.users.createTable()
            await db.stores.createTable()
            await db.booths.createTable()
            await db.reservations.createTable()
            await db.clothing.createTable()
            console.log('finished!')
            resolve()
        })
    })
    describe('running datalayer test suite', async () => {
        try {
            console.log('starting tests')
            await userTest()
            await storeTest()
            await boothTest()
            await reservationTest()
            await clothingTest()
        } catch (e) {
            console.warn(e)
        }
    })
    after('destroying db', async () => {
        await db.clothing.dropTable()
        await db.reservations.dropTable()
        await db.booths.dropTable()
        await db.stores.dropTable()
        await db.users.dropTable()

    })
})
```

```
starting tests
(node:16339) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: something went wrong with persisting the store: error: relation "stores" does not exist
    at module.exports (/home/jonas/Projects/sellsome-backend/exceptions/query-exception.js:2:19)
    at Object.insert (/home/jonas/Projects/sellsome-backend/logiclayer/stores.js:23:19)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:16339) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2)
(node:16339) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
..... tons more
finished!
```

---

Edit: Mocha version 8.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally I am not much for answering my own questions - but removing the inner describe block fixed it perfectly. I am yet to figure out exactly why.

```js
describe('', async () => {
    before('setting up database', async () => {
        return new Promise(async resolve => {
            await db.users.createTable()
            await db.stores.createTable()
            await db.booths.createTable()
            await db.reservations.createTable()
            await db.clothing.createTable()
            console.log('finished!')
            resolve()
        })
    })
    try {
        console.log('starting tests')
        await userTest()
        await storeTest()
        await boothTest()
        await reservationTest()
        await clothingTest()
    } catch (e) {
       console.warn(e)
    }
    after('destroying db', async () => {
        await db.clothing.dropTable()
        await db.reservations.dropTable()
        await db.booths.dropTable()
        await db.stores.dropTable()
        await db.users.dropTable()

    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experiences a similiar issue before, but im unsure if this is the same.

Try this style please. Note the `async function()` instead of arrow functions.

```
before('setting up database', async function() {
       await db.users.createTable()
       await db.stores.createTable()
       await db.booths.createTable()
       await db.reservations.createTable()
       await db.clothing.createTable()
       console.log('finished!')
})
```

Comment: after replacing all the arrow functions with regular functions, I can sadly report that the outcome is the same..

Comment: please try removing the ```async``` from the surrouding ```describe``` block

Comment: I thought that could do the trick, but it behaves the same with or without the ```àsync```

Answer (score 0):

Do check your mocha version, as I know for the previous version it was something like

```
before(function (done) {
   db.collection('user').remove({}, function (res) { done(); }); // It is now guaranteed to finish before 'it' starts.
})
```

`done()` is the key here

In new version it's like

```
let message = '';
before(() => {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      message = "hello";
      resolve();
    }, 10);
  });
});
it('message should be hello', () => {
  assert(message === 'hello');
});
```

[Link](https://mochajs.org/#working-with-promises)

Comment: my mocha version is the most recent 8.1.1